# Send data between two instances of the same program

Tags: c#, wpf

I'm just about done battling the Mutex and Single Instance for my program.

I've got it working to the point where I can check if my program has another instance running.

But here's what I now trying to figure out:

If I have another instance running, I want to send data from the new instance to the old one.

Here's the scenario for my musicplayer:

User clicks an mp3 file, and it opens in a new instance.

The new instance sees that there's already an instance open and sends the filepath(s) to the first instance.

How do you do these kind of things? 
Any place to read about it would be awesome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been working at exactly same problem atm. [In this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) you can read about all usable interprocess communication mechanisms.

I choose to use TCP sockets in my project. Here you can find [server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5w7b7x5f%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and [client](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) app examples.

Approximate algorithm is:

1. Check is process with same name running
2. If no, create server socket and start listening to client
   connections using BeginAccept method
3. If the same instance has been already running, create client socket,
   send data and close instance
4. When server side get data it process data and continue listening
5. When user close program, you must end listening

Note that you must dispose sockets before exit. Also you should listen in a background thread and use synchronization mechanisms (like EventWaitHandle) to wait until receive data from client before go to the next one.